# Update SQL SERVER Fecha

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo una tabla donde una columna tiene el formato datetime fecha de la siguiente forma `YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00.000`, donde la parte time siempre es `00:00:00.000`, sin embargo, hay ocasiones en las que al actualizar datos en esa tabla la hora, minutos, segundos adquiere un valor distinto (viene en los datos a actualizar).

Mi pregunta es: ¿Hay alguna manera de corregir esto con un update u otra forma para que si alguna fecha tiene esos valores diferentes a 0 los ponga a 0, sin alterar la fecha?

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Por favor, modifica tu pregunta aportando algún fragmento de código con el intento que hayas hecho. Te sugiero un simple `UPDATE tabla SET campo=DATE(campo)`

Comment: Buenas, no intento adaptar ningún código, lo único que hago hasta ahora es exportar las fechas que no están con el time a 00:00:00.000  ( ejemplo 2021-01-02 10:03:53.000 ) y en una hoja excel creo un Update que para esa fecha si es  "2021-01-02 00:00:00.000) , lo que estoy buscando es si hay otra forma sin tener que exportar, y trabajar con fórmulas de excel para cortar "time" y añadirlo a cero

Comment: Depende de como estés haciendo está actualización que dices, hay varias formas de eliminar la parte horaria de una fecha/hora, pero deberías explicar mejor como funciona está actualización, desde dónde la haces, por medio de que lenguaje, etc

Comment: Si nunca usas la hora ¿Por qué no cambiar el tipo de dato de la tabla a `date` en vez de dejarlo en `datetime`?

Comment: Buenas, gracias por las ideas, el problema es que sólo tengo acceso a la base de datos, no debo intervenir en la actualización de esos datos y tampoco debo cambiar el tipo de dato de la tabla (podría afectar a terceros), ya se que solo pongo problemas, gracias otra vez

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es recuperar sin información de hora los datos que están en la base de datos, puedes seguir alguna de estas recomendaciones en tu consulta:

- Puedes obtener solo la parte `date` del campo, que no tiene información de hora, solamente la fecha:

  ```
    select campo1, campo2, cast(fecha as date) fecha
      from tabla
     where condiciones
  ```
- Si necesitas tener un campo de tipo `DateTime`, puedes aplicar la misma técnica de convertir a `Date` para quitar la parte de la hora, y de nuevo convertirlo en un `DateTime` que, en este caso, siempre tendrá hora `00:00:00.000`:

  ```
    select campo1, campo2, cast(cast(fecha as date) as DateTime) fecha
      from tabla
     where condiciones
  ```
- La menos recomendable, pero que no puedo dejar de mencionar, es que puedes obtener una representación textual de la fecha, que en ocasiones puede facilitarte las cosas, dependiendo de para qué vas a utilizar los datos que arroja la consulta. Por ejemplo, para  obtener la fecha en formato `yyyy-mm-dd` utiliza la función `convert()`:

  ```
    select campo1, campo2, convert(varchar(10), fecha, 23)  fecha
      from tabla
     where condiciones
  ```

  Encontrarás más información de los formatos de fecha disponibles en la [documentación de la función *convert()*](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Si lo que quieres es actualizar la tabla para *truncar* la información de hora y que siempre sea las `00:00:00.000`, puedes realizar la siguiente actualización de datos:

```
update tabla
   set fecha = cast(fecha as date)
 where fecha <> cast(fecha as date)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, justo lo que estaba buscando.